# What are the differences between running Python through an IDE and terminal?

Tags: terminal, python-idle

What are the differences between running Python code through an IDE and terminal? When I run my code in PyCharm it works, however when I try to run the same code in terminal I get NameError, etc.

Answer (score 0):

An exact answer depends on the exact IDE and the exact terminal one compares on a particular OS.  The IDLE doc chapter, accessible from IDLE's Help menu, has a section '3.3. IDLE-console differences '.  Some of these apply to other IDEs.

One possible difference not discussed is language differences.  IDLE runs user code directly with python, as is.  Other IDEs add language extensions or command escapes.

Your issue with NameErrors suggests that PyCharm inserts something into globals that standard python does not.  A few years ago, a couple of Stackoverflowers reported extra name issues with IDLE, which I fixed.  For anyone to say anything more, you would have to add specific code and the resulting traceback to your question.